# Webhook HTTP STATUS 500

Tags: plesk, git

My webserver has multiple domains that I manage with PLESK. Each domain is connected to a git repository on bitbucket.org:

[image]

I have set SSH Keys and webhook in my bitbucket repository.

The automatic webhook that is triggered on a push event. This works for all my websites, except for one. I double checked the SSH key and webhook url, both are correct.

I can see the content of the request body, but I did not find any information why the response was not working. I only got ***HTTP status 500***.

[image]

Any ideas how I may spot the issue?

Comment: More information about 500 errors can be found in your error log.  Without the log information you won't know what the specific problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I clicked manually on "Pull updates" in Plesk, an error message appeared:

> error cannot open /var/.../git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied

[image]

I had to change user permission (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13195882/2311074)  and then manual pull and the webhook was working correctly. I am still wondering if there is anywhere a web hook issue log.